# How to install application on avd?

Tags: android-sdk

I try to install application on android avd but i cant 
can you help me to install any android store ?

```
./adb install '/home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/mobogenie_1028.apk' 
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash (the terminal) is basically saying it cannot find the file `adb` in your working directory. `./` means "the directory I'm in". By typing `./adb` you try to excecute the file `adb` that is in your current working directory.

What I think you might want to do is this:

```
adb install '/home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/mobogenie_1028.apk'
```

This excecutes the installed program `adb`.